# MS Access: How to open form via command button based on current record?

Tags: ms-access

Let's say I've got two tables, `tblA` and `tblB`, that have a 1:n relationship, i.e. for a given record in tblA there can be many records in tblB.

Now I have a form, `frmA`, that is based on tblA. On this form there is a command button that opens a second form, `frmB`, that is based on `tblB`. Now I want that second form `frmB` to only display records from `tblB` that match the current record from `tblA`.
I found that there is a built-in way (I use Access 2010) that filters the data from `tblB`. But since within `frmB` I need to do some more stuff based on the current record, this is not enough.
How do I do this then?

I thought of creating a query, `qryAB`, that does an inner join and has a parameter to select a certain record from `tblA`. But how would I pass something to this query to use as a parameter from the on-click macro (or vba) for my command button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Where argument of the [OpenForm method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238021%28v=office.12%29.aspx), you can add OpenArgs to OpenForm and you can refer to an already open form in code. It all depends on what you want to do next.

Comment: I'll try a more detailed description: Table A contains data on business partners. Form A displays these (together with a subform for contact persons). Now for each record from table A I want a command button that opens a new form (pop-up) that lists only the entries (agreements) from table B that correspond to the current record from A. On this form I additionally need a combo-box that is based on the current selection and is used for navigation in the records displayed in form B (e.g. a combobox with all the years for which an agreement with the business partner exists)..

Comment: If formB is always opened from formA, you can set the rowsource of the combo to, say, `SELECT FROM Table WHERE AField=Forms!formA!SomeControl`. However, you may not need to reference the form at all, after all, the form now shows only the records where the id matches formA, so your rowsource can reference formB ID. Finally, you can pass a reference as an OpenArg and build the combo by code. As a general rule, I try to avoid forms that don't work as stand-alone and I try to build combos that will work based on the information available on the current form.

Comment: Using the OpenForm method together with an appropriate select statement seems to do the job. And I can then make the combobox on form B be based on the information available on that form. I'm not that familiar with Access and sometimes a bit lost as to which way to do things works best... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered making frmb a subform of frma and using the parent child relationship.

Comment: I've considered it, but I don't think that in my scenario (see my comment to Remou's answer) this is exactly what I want..